# devise controller filters, create new controller or can I use them on defs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I have a user model that can create an application.

The application controller contains, new, create, edit and show.

What I would like is that everybody logged in or not should be able to see the content in the #show, whilst the ability to create, edit etc is restricted to the user.

Is the best option to create a new controller that contains a #show and displays all the data from the previous controller, or can I somehow put a restriction on everything except show in my current controller?

What's best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a permissions managing gem? [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is pretty popular, and has a nice DSL for restricting certain controller actions based on a simple ruleset which you can define.